# passing dynamic value to onclick function - CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I was trying to pass an id to onclick function but it returns wrong value when I used it on my view.

My function in my model that gets the ID in the database:

```
public function _get_pr_id()
{
    $this->db->select('pr_id');
    $this->db->from('tblprequest');
    $this->db->order_by('pr_date_created', 'DESC');
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $row = $query->row();
    return $row->pr_id;
}
```

The purpose of this function is that it gets the latest `pr_id` inserted in the database. Example is that '15'.

And here is my Controller:

```
public function purchase_request()
{
    if ($this->session->userdata('username'))
    {
        $data = array(
            'item' => $this->pr->_get_item(),
            'dept' => $this->pr->_get_department(),
            'pr_id' => $this->pr->_get_pr_id(),
            'admin_content' => 'pages/admin_purchase_request'
        );
        $this->load->view('admin_template/admin', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('login');
    }
}
```

I store the value of the function `$this->pr->_get_pr_id()` to a variable `pr_id` so that I can use it in my View with AJAX.

And here is the View:

```
<a onclick="finalize('<?php echo $pr_id; ?>')" id="finalize" class="btn btn-success" aria-expanded="false">Finalize <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a>
```

And my function in my View:

```
function finalize(id)
{
   alert(id);
}
```

Now, the problem:
For example in my db, the latest `pr_id` is `15` but when I click the `finalize` button it says to me the `pr_id` is `14`.
Hope you understand my question. Thanks

Comment: Your code looks fine. Verify once the value with db. Also make sure that when you load request and click button between that data not inserted into db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your pr_id  is auto-increment column then just order by your result using pr_id. Because ordering by integer column is fast.
And in your case there is a possibility of new record is inserted after you fetched the latest pr_id. So there is no fool-proof solution
to handle your case.
 So, When you call `finalize()`, again check your current pr_id value is latest one. Based on that you could handle your logic.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have to use ajax with the onclick event this way you are sure you get the last value from database, in the use case you described, there is another source that updated the database after you grab the data, so using ajax will provide the last stored value, you can use something similar to :

```
$(document).on("click",".yourselector",function(e){

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "controller/function",
    data: {
        param: myparamvalue
    },
    beforeSend: function() {

    },
    complete: function() {

    },
    success: function(_result) {

    }
});

});
```

where Controller is the controller that call the model using the method to grab the id from db

if not working plz replace :

```
controller/function
```

by this :

```
/controller/function
```

Hoe it helps,